# Check for Magento Cart for products with a specific AttributeSetName

Tags: magento

In Magento checkout/cart I would like to check if products from six specific attributesets is added to the Magento cart.

I have created the function below to check a productview page for these attributesetname(s), but how do I do the same check for items in the checkout/cart?

```
$attribute_set = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load( $_product->getAttributeSetId() ); 
$attributeset_name = $attribute_set->getAttributeSetName();
if ($attributeset_name =="Sko" or $attributeset_name =="beklaedning" or $attributeset_name =="Banz_solhat" or $attributeset_name =="Soltoj" or $attributeset_name =="solhat" or $attributeset_name =="fodtoj") { 
    echo "<b>Fragt</b>: <span style='color:red'>Fri Fragt p&aring; varen samt resten af ordren</span><br>"; 
}
```

Best regards, 
Jesper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$attributeSetNames = array('Sko', 'beklaedning', 'Banz_solhat', 'Soltoj', 'solhat', 'fodtoj');

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection();
$itemCollection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft( 
        array('cp' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product')), 
        'cp.entity_id = main_table.product_id', 
        array('cp.attribute_set_id'))
    ->joinLeft( 
        array('eas' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('eav/attribute_set')), 
        'cp.attribute_set_id = eas.attribute_set_id', 
        array('eas.attribute_set_name'))
;
$itemCollection->setQuote($quote);

foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->getData('attribute_set_name'), $attributeSetNames)) {
       //... Match
    }
}
```

---

**Alternatively**…

Use the attribute set ids instead of names.  This would avoid any potential issues with wording and also clean the code up a little…

```
$attributeSetIds = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection();
$itemCollection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft( 
        array('cp' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product')), 
        'cp.entity_id = main_table.product_id', 
        array('cp.attribute_set_id'))
;
$itemCollection->setQuote($quote);

foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->getData('attribute_set_id'), $attributeSetIds)) {
       //... Match
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Drew, Thank you very much for your reply :-) Could you please also help me with a code snip to check if a certain shopping cart rule id is complied to an order (if complied, then echo...)